# Find recorset with variable name

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I've defined a global variable : chosen_operator
then, i need to search a form and find recordset with  this variable in the field [op_choice]

trying :

```
Dim rstformat As Recordset

With Forms("form_list_of_columns").rstformat  
.FindFirst CHOSEN_OPERATOR
End With
```

does not work

i also tried with

```
DoCmd.FindRecord CHOSEN_OPERATOR,, True,, True
```

always tell me object not defined or ... does not match method ....

any idea ?

Comment: thanks but i've got error 3070 - database does not recognize 'op_choice'  as valid field name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
With Forms("form_list_of_columns").Recordset  
.FindFirst "[op_choice]='" & CHOSEN_OPERATOR & "'"
End With
```

If [op_choice] is numeric, remove single quotes

Comment: thanks but i've got error 3070 - database does not recognize 'op_choice' as valid field name

Comment: You mentioned [op_choice] as a variable where you should search. I supposed that you meant the field in form's base query. Here you should use the name of field of form's base query where you are trying to find the value, stored in global variable.

Comment: [op_choice] is the textbox in the form_list_of_columns

Comment: sorry - pressed enter too quickly . [op_choice] is the textbox in the form_list_of_columns and CHOSEN_OPERATOR is the defined variable that i m looking for in that field [op_choice]

Comment: You need to know the name of field in QUERY, not textbox name, they may be the same though. Check Control Source property of your textbox, normally it has the query/table field name

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted and upvote if it helped to solve the problem, it will help others to find solutions

Comment: Thanks. Probably you don't have rights for this yet. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers